# Adding another route in Asp.net mvc3 not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this route map defined.

```
  routes.MapRoute("default", // route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // url with parameters
            new { controller = "home", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // parameter defaults
            new string[] { "mobilesurveys.mt.controllers" }
        );
```

This will work perfectly. now I want to add another routemap

```
   routes.MapRoute("couponreedem", // route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{clientname}", // url with parameters
            new { controller = "Rc", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // parameter defaults
            new string[] { "mobilesurveys.mt.controllers" }
        );
```

i have defined like this. Here Rc is my controller. and I am giving the url as
     .com /Rc/Rc/sammy

and method in the controller defined as

```
  public ActionResult Rc(string clientname)
    {

        viewModel =dataRc.ProductCategoryGet();
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

clientname will be always null. How to add another route while the existing route not be disturbed.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like both of your routes are identical, why do you need the second one?

Comment: Unless you're hung up on having the parameter as "clientname" rather than, "id" - I would just stick with "id" and you won't need to define a second route (couponreedem). Else, fix the parameter in your second route map (couponreedem) - changing "id = Url.Paremeter.Optional" to  "clientname = Url.Paremeter.Optional". Also, unless you're using "Areas", you don't need to specify the namespace for your controllers.

Answer (score 1):

It actually looks identical. But in case you want a new one you can try something like this, and it should be above the default one.

```
 routes.MapRoute("couponreedem", // route name
            "RC/{action}/{clientname}", // url with parameters
            new { controller = "Rc", action = "index", clientname = UrlParameter.Optional }, // parameter defaults
            new string[] { "mobilesurveys.mt.controllers" }
        );
```

That will fix the route with RC/... 
Also your action should be named Index

```
  public ActionResult Index (string clientname)
    {

        viewModel =dataRc.ProductCategoryGet();
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```